# Simple (but complex) layout design with SwiftUI

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to code a simple layout design with SwiftUI without success!

Here's what I'd like to do:

```
ScrollView {
    VStrack {
        // Header with an orange background.
        // This orange color should also apply to the status bar.
    }
    VStrack {
        // Content with a white background.
        // This white color should always go to the bottom.
    }
}
```

I first tried to apply an orange background to the first `VStack` and a white background to the second `VStack` but I couldn't color the status bar in orange even with `.ignoresSafeArea()`.

Then I tried to apply an orange background to the `ScrollView` and a white background again to the second `VStack` but I couldn't color the bottom of the screen in white even with `.infinity`.

I also tried to use `LazyVStack` but nothing happened.

Do you guys have any idea to make this works? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting the height of the content to be at least the screen height:

```
.frame(minHeight: UIScreen.screenHeight)
```

Here's the sample code of the full view's body (you can replace the `HStack`s with `VStack`s, as long as you fill the width):

```
        ScrollView {
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Header")
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            .background(.orange)
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Content")
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            .frame(minHeight: UIScreen.screenHeight, alignment: .top)
            .background(.white)
        }
        .background(Color.orange.ignoresSafeArea(.all, edges: .top))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! When I'm using the `UIScreen.screenHeight` modifier I get this error message: "Type 'UIScreen' has no member 'screenHeight'". Is it normal?

Comment: Alright, I used `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` instead and it works. I'm not really happy that the content is way higher than the screen but it's better than nothing. Thanks a lot @HunterLion.